# Nginx as reverse proxy for Spring WebFlux changes streaming behavior

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, spring-webflux, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have developed a Spring Boot application that have RequestController's which returns a list Flux of objects.

Using the web application directly it works perfect. I get each object as my application have them ready.

But when I am running the application behind a reverse proxy using nginx I see a different behavior. Now I am not getting the result until the whole flux stream is ready.

So before I would get the first object in a second and the last after 20 seconds have passed. Now I get all objects after 20 seconds.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/flux", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Message> flux() {
    return messageService.getFluxStream();
}
```

Nginx setup:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name domain.tk www.domain.tk;
return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
# SSL configuration

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

server_name domain.tk www.domain.tk;

location / {
    proxy_pass                    http://localhost:8082;
    proxy_pass_request_headers    on;
    #proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    #proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    #proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
}
}
```

My DNS is cloudflare and I have a certificate from them and is proxying traffic cloudflare.

In the nginx log I won't get see the request being logged before all the objects is ready after the 20 seconds as well. Which makes me think it's not a cloudflare proxy issue, but likely more a nginx setup issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason to the chosen `MediaType` as i suspect it has something to with the headers. Please supply your raw request and your raw response so we actually see the difference in responses/headers etc depending on proxy or no proxy

Comment: I originally used application/json+streaming but that was deprecated with a comment that ndjson shold be used instead. But I found the problem and will update with answer. Thanks for you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a buffering issue. Adding proxy_buffering off; to the location block in nginx configuration solved it.